# Social sharing cordova plugin

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am working with social share cordova plugin to share PDF via whatsapp.
Plugin version : *****cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing@6.0.3*****
Package version : **@awesome-cordova-plugins/social-sharing@5.37.3**
Below is my code:

```
public shareViaWhatsApp(textMessage:string,fileURL?:string,url?:string): Promise<any>
{
textMessage=textMessage;
fileURL=fileURL ? decodeURI(fileURL) : null;
url=url?decodeURI(url) : null;

return this.share.shareViaWhatsApp(textMessage, fileURL,url);}
```

The above code works perfectly fine for the link:
[pdf_1](https://www.hdfclife.com/content/dam/hdfclifeinsurancecompany/products-page/brochure-pdf/018797019-HDFC-Life-Click-2-Wealth_Brochure_Retail_V3.pdf)
.Successful message : [image]

But doesnt work for the link : [sanchay brochure](https://brandsite-static.hdfclife.com/media/documents/apps/sanchay%20broucher.pdf).
Error message : `sharing failed, please try again`.
[image]

Could anyone please assist me in fixing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

you can try capacitor share plugin for the same.

this code might help you.

const fileResult = await Filesystem.getUri({
directory: Directory.Cache,
path: fileName
});

```
  const fileLink = Capacitor.convertFileSrc(fileResult.uri);

  await Share.share({
    title: fileName,
    text: fileName,
    files: [fileLink],
  })
    .then(() => console.log("Successful share"))
    .catch((error) => console.log("Error sharing ::: ", error));
```